# Submitting form with jQuery .ajax() or .post() on Native iPhone Phonegap app?

Tags: php, jquery, iphone, ajax, cordova

I was wondering how will I use jQuery's `.ajax()` or `.post()` to send data to a php file on my webserver from a Phonegap Native iPhone App?
Does it have to be xml or json? Or can I just send regular html post data to the file?

If you can show me an example that would be great!

UPDATE: Thanks Drew for the stellar solution! I also found an article that explained the process pretty well too.

UPDATE 2: There is a problem with my script.

Here is my javascript. I am trying to have jQuery send my sign in form data over to my PHP file. I then tell it to grab the data from the php file and display it. But all that is coming back is "null". If I request another value such as bio, it can display it. But it cant display data sent from my form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").click(function() {
            var data = $('form#signin').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:'signin.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: data,
                success:function(data) {
                    $("p.test").html(data);
                    $.getJSON("signin.php", function(data) {
                        localStorage.email = data[0];

                    });
                },
                error:function(data) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my PHP

```
<?php

$email = $_POST["email"];

$profile = array($email, "Karl", "Clement", "Gangsta Love!", "bio bio bio bio bio bio    bio     bio bio bio bio bio bio bio bio bio bio bio", "Ottawa",     "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/1459354642/IMG_1560_normal.jpg");

header('Content-Type:text/json');
echo json_encode($profile);

?>
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your best bet is JSON, but you can submit like a normal form. Try some experiments  -

```
$.ajax({
   url:'formPage.php',
   type:'POST',
   data:'name=john&email=john@smith.com',
   success:function(data){
     console.log(data);
   },
   error:function(w,t,f){
     console.log(w+' '+t+' '+f);
   }
});
```

should work just fine. You could also just do JSON

```
    $.ajax({
       url:'formPage.php',
       type:'POST',
       data:{name:'john',email:'john@smith.com'},
       success:function(data){
         console.log(data);
       },
       error:function(w,t,f){
         console.log(w+' '+t+' '+f);
       }
    });
```

To start I would just have your app send a request to your server and have it return a statement, that way you can see that it connects and responds, then start passing variables!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Its a big help! One little question, if I use the second method, will it post the values with http post? Could I receive these values by $_POST('name') in my php file? Or do I have to decode it? If so, how would I do that in php to get them under php variables?

Comment: you can totally set it with your php using JSON. If you are using php you can submit using the first method and receive the values like you normally would with $_POST, if you do JSON you'll need to do a json_decode check out - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thank you very very much Drew. You have saved a lot of trouble. I will use json just to be safe!

Comment: One more thing, if I use json to post to my php file, how do I access the data to json_encode it? Can you write me a PHP example? After that i'll stop bugging you. I accepted the answer btw.

Comment: I am actually in the middle of writing a tutorial about making a basic RESTful API for phonegap... ill post link when done!

Comment: That's great! Thanks Drew. Looking forward to reading your tut!

Comment: Hey Drew, I posted an update to my question because I am not able to pass on data to my PHP. Can you have a look? Thank you so much!